# Can AssemblyQualifiedTypeNameConverter attribute get the generic type from the fully qualified name from configuration file?

Tags: .net

I have a configuration classes which get the elements.
Some of them is of a Type value. I am using AssemblyQualifiedTypeNameConverter so that the
fully qualified name can be converted to a Type.

Is it possible for that attribute to get the generic Type?

From hand it is possible. I can obtain generic type, MakeGenericType and createInstance from activator....

Answer (score 0):

I have solved. 
The fully qualified name has to be written with: "`1" in the end. No it works.